# Operating system development - dynamic memory allocation

Tags: linux, operating-system, malloc

I want to develop my own operating system from the beginning. But I have some doubts about dynamic memory allocation. For example: There will be a linked list that implements a ready process queue. When I allocate memory in my programs, I use malloc. But, could I use malloc directly in the kernel implementation? Or I must develop my own memory allocator? I am not sure, but I think that malloc uses system calls to check the page table, so I could not use that in my own kernel. If I cant use malloc, how could I allocate memory for the queue?

Thanks.

Comment: Will you use virtual memory?

Comment: Yes, I will use the MMU resource. I want to do an operating system like linux, but not too advanced. I want basic features that every SO has, like scheduling, virtual memory (segmentation with paging), file system, network stack, etc.

Comment: And, if you know someone who has experience in operating system development, I would like to talk to him to exchange some ideas. Thanks for replying.